# Understanding calibrating probabilities using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, calibration

I am trying to understand R's calibration(`package:caret`) function. My main interest is binary classification. Calibration function is used for plotting true probabilities vs predicted probabilities. I wonder the algorithm for true probabilities. The packages document is at below link:

[CRAN: caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf)

What is its algorithm? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks  lot.

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/561922/247274) addresses a different package (`rms`) but the same idea.