# Create calibration plot in R with vectors of predicted and observed values

Tags: r, regression, self-study, predictive-models, calibration

I am currently working on a project regarding the external validation of a logistic regression model for binary classification. I would like to create a calibration plot and compute the calibration-in-the-large (intercept) and calibration slope, like the following figure.

I noted that most online tutorials involved using the lrm object in R to compute the calibration-in-the-large and calibration slope. However, no lrm object is available for my project as the logistic regression results are calculated elsewhere. Instead, I have two vectors, one contains all predicted values (e.g. 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1 ...), the other contains observed values (e.g. 0, 1, 1, 0 ...).
[image]

I am currently plotting the calibration curve manually by breaking all observations into quantiles and calculating the mean observed risk and the mean predicted risk in each quantile. I wonder if there is a way to get the calibration-in-the-large and calibration slope by using the two vectors only. It would be best if there is a way to create a sophisticated calibration plot (like the attached one with zone of confidence interval ) directly from two vectors without any manual calculation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You can validate the probabilities using `rms::val.prob`, which checks if, when a probability of $p$ is claimed, the event indeed happens with probability $p$ (e.g., can't have events with claimed probability $0.5$ almost never happening). A [question of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/594393/247274) asks how damaging it would be to do this when really you should be doing calibration. // Why not develop the logistic regression in the `rms` package?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is check if, when an event probability of $p$ is predicted by the model, the event indeed happens with probability $p$. After all, there is a sense in which the model is lying if it keeps predicting events to have probability of $0.5$ that almost never (or almost always) happen. Likewise, low and high predicted probabilities should correspond to events that rarely and frequently occur, respectively.

An `R` function to do this is `rms::val.prob` from Frank Harrell's `rms` package. If the claimed probabilities are reflective of the reality of how often the event occurs, that will correspond to a 45-degree line.

```
library(rms)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
probability <- runif(N, 0, 1)
event <- rbinom(N, 1, probability)
rms::val.prob(probability, event)
```

[image]

By the construction of this simulation, the fit is almost the ideal. However, funky probability values result in a grossly non-ideal fit (though both have the same $c$-index, equal to the area under the ROC curve, since I applied a strictly increasing transformation to the probabilities).

```
library(rms)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
probability <- runif(N, 0, 1)
event <- rbinom(N, 1, probability)
rms::val.prob(probability^2, event)
```

[image]

An advantage of doing the probability validation with `rms::val.prob` instead of using quantiles is that you don't have to rely on somewhat arbitrary binning; you smoothly evaluate all data all at once.

A [question of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594393/how-damaging-to-the-analysis-would-it-be-to-run-probability-validation-rmsva) asks how damaging to the analysis it would be to run `val.prob` when calibration is the truly correct action. My sentiment from [the answer by EdM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/603449/247274) is that, while `val.prob` is not ideal, the damage is not so enormous.