# Predicted class probability in threshold moving

Tags: classification, binary-data, threshold, h2o

I am training a model for the task of **Binary classification** using **H2O.ai**. The final output to the user is the probability of `class_1`.

Recently, I found that by default the training uses **threshold moving**, and all the `test_f1` are the scores found after moving the threshold.

Now, Let's say the class_1 probability is `90%`, while the threshold is set at `94%`. The user will be completely sure that it's a true instance while the model actually classified it as false.

My question is how can We interpret the probability of a class in a task of binary classification while threshold moving has been applied?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To be meaningful as probability values, you will want them to be calibrated. That is, when a prediction of $P$ is made, the event should happen about $P$ proportion of the times. Concretely, if you keep predicting an event to happen with $90\%$ probability, yet the event happens in only $60\%$ of the cases, your prediction of $0.9$ lacks calibration.

It is not a given that your predictions will be calibrated probability values.

The two links below discuss software tools and the statistical ideas implemented in them for assessing probability calibration. I do not know of an implementation besides R, but I once ported basic functionality of `val.prob` to Python without much difficulty, so it can be done.

[Walk through `rms::calibrate` for logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/561956/247274)

[Walk through `rms::val.prob`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563867/walk-through-rmsval-prob)